# Fresco dependency ломает aar библиотеку

Tags: java, android, unity3d, gradle

Я импортирую unity3d проект как aar библиотеку в android проект.

Изначально для ускорения работы я завел пустой android и отлаживал связь с юнити в нем, все работало, когда пришло время соединить unity aar с моим основным проектом получил ошибку при запуске юнити :

> No implementation found for void
>   com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRestartActivityIndicator()

Тогда я копировал все dependencies из основного проекта в пустой и получил ту же ошибку, затем я вычислил  что ошибка происходит когда включена библиотека Fresco, при этом она даже не используется нигде в коде.

Вот как выглядит конечный Gradle dependencies пустого проекта

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.11.0'// так не работает, если удалить, то работает.
    implementation project(':UnityAar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}
```

Как такое вообще может быть? И что делать?

PS просто удалить Fresco нельзя, на ней работает основной проект.

Answer (score 0):

Починил так:

Build.gradle(Module app)

```
android{
   //....
   defaultConfig {
        //...
        ndk {
            abiFilters  "armeabi-v7a", "x86" // такие же и в unity
        }
    }
}
```

Хотя размер apk вырос в разы. Но думаю google play разделит их.

Как я понял Fresco, также как и unity,  использует [нативный код](https://frescolib.org/docs/shipping.html) и видимо где-то произошла не стыковка, как вариант ABI unity не совпадал с ABI fresco(хотя я об этом ничего не знаю)... В общем вопрос "Как такое вообще может быть?" - остается открытым.